# How to convert text-to-speech in react native?

Tags: react-native

I am doing form validation in react-native and I want to do some text-to-speech conversion. I installed this library `react-native-speech`. But when I compile my code I get this error (I am using Expo):

```
TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 'NativeSpeechSynthesizer.stopSpeakingAtBoundary')
```

And my code is:

```
import Speech from 'react-native-speech';

signIn () {
    if (this.state.email == "") {
        Speech.speak({
        text: 'Email is required',
        voice: 'en_US'
        })
        return false
    }
    else {...}
}
.....

<Button onPress={() => this.signIn() }>
    Sign in
</Button>
```

Does anyone know how to solve this problem?

Thanks.